# How to structure the NodeJs code

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am new to the NodeJs. I have created a simple application using `socket.io`. I know that I can use `ExpressJs` framework but I am not getting overall idea as to `how to separate the code` and `divide them into multiple page`s so that debugging and maintenance is easily.

I am not understanding `how to structure the code` and where to write the socket.io code or any other NodeJs code in general.

Should I create new folder and files? If yes then how?

My code: app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var ent = require('ent');
var fs = require('fs');

var cntActiveProductSupport = 0;
var cntActiveCustomer = 0;
var support_socket_id = '';

app.get('/',function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.get('/product_support',function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/admin.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket,username){
    //Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id
    console.log(socket.id);
    //total number of connections
    console.log(io.engine.clientsCount);

    socket.on('support_connected',function(username){
        username = ent.encode(username);
        socket.username = username;
        socket.broadcast.emit('support_connected',username);
        //get socket id of all connected sockets
        Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach(function(id) {
            console.log("ID:",id)  // socketId
        });

        cntActiveProductSupport++;
        support_socket_id = socket.id;
    });

    socket.on('new_client',function(username){
        var client_socket_id = socket.id;
        username = ent.encode(username);
        socket.username = username;
        socket.broadcast.emit('new_client',{ username: username, socket_id: socket.id, support_socket_id: support_socket_id });
        socket.to(client_socket_id).emit('client_connected',{ username: username, support_socket_id: support_socket_id });

        cntActiveCustomer++;
    });

    socket.on('message',function(data){
        //socket.disconnect(true); use this if you want to disconnect client from server
        //client which sent the message
        var client_socket_id = socket.id;
        var message = ent.encode(data.message);
        // sending to individual socketid (private message)
        //socket.to(socketId).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
        socket.to(support_socket_id).emit('message', {username: socket.username,message:message, client_socket_id: client_socket_id});
    });

    socket.on('support_messaging',function(data){
        message = ent.encode(data.message);
        var customer_socket_id = data.customer_socket_id;
        //socket.broadcast.emit('message', {username: socket.username,message:message});
        // sending to individual socketid (private message)
        socket.broadcast.to(customer_socket_id).emit('message', {username: socket.username,message:message});
        //socket.to(socketId).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
        //It's the same command as for rooms, that's because:
        //"For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id."
    });

    socket.on('typing',function(username){
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', username);
    });

    socket.on('stopped-typing',function(){
        socket.broadcast.emit('stopped-typing');
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

My code: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Real-time Super Chat!</title>
    <style>
        #zone_chat strong {
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        #writeup {
            font-size:9px;
            color: gray;
            margin: 5px 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h4>Real-time Super Chat!</h4>

<form action="/" method="post" id="chat_form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message..." size="50" />
    <input type="submit" id="send_message" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="support_socket_id" value=""/>
    <div id="writeup"></div>
</form>

<section id="chat_zone">

</section>


<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    // Connecting to socket.io
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var socketConnected = false;

    // The username is requested, sent to the server and displayed in the title
    var username = prompt('What\'s your username?');
    //var username = 'Deepak';
    socket.emit('new_client', username);
    document.title = username + ' - ' + document.title;

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socketConnected = true;
        console.log('Connected! ID: ' + socket.id);
    });

    socket.on('client_connected', function(data){
        $('#support_socket_id').val(data.support_socket_id);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socketConnected = false;
        console.log('Disconnected!');
    });

    // When a message is received it's inserted in the page
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        insertMessage(data.username, data.message)
    });

    // When a new client connects, the information is displayed
    // socket.on('new_client', function(username) {
    //     $('#chat_zone').prepend('<p><em>' + username + ' has joined the chat!</em></p>');
    // });

    socket.on('typing',function(username){
        $('#writeup').html(username + ' is typing...');
    });

    socket.on('stopped-typing',function(){
        $('#writeup').html('');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#message').on('focus',function(){
            socket.emit('typing',username);
        });

        $('#message').on('blur',function(){
            socket.emit('stopped-typing',username);
        });

        // When the form is sent, the message is sent and displayed on the page
        $('#chat_form').submit(function () {
            var message = $('#message').val();
            var support_socket_id = $('#support_socket_id').val();
            socket.emit('message', { message:message, support_socket_id:support_socket_id }); // Sends the message to the others
            insertMessage(username, message); // Also displays the message on our page
            $('#message').val('').focus(); // Empties the chat form and puts the focus back on it
            return false; // Blocks 'classic' sending of the form

        });
    });

    // Adds a message to the page
    function insertMessage(username, message) {
        $('#chat_zone').prepend('<p><strong>' + username + '</strong> ' + message + '</p>');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is very broad.  There are hundreds of ways to structure your code - there is no "standard" way that is any more right than other ways.  This is pretty much no different than any other programming language.  You divide your code into meaningful modules (whatever is meaningful in your own design) and then you import/export to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

You should create node modules in order to maintain the code structure. For example create routes folder and put all the route in there and separate them like users.js is a route file to cater routing related to user. As you are using socket.io you can create a separate module for socket.io functions and use them in your routes.

This link might help you: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

I hope it helps.

App Structure: routes,  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlBBR.png)